# Axis of approximate symmetry in irregular polygons

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2

Does anyone have an idea how to determine the axis of approximate symmetry in irregular convex polygon? (Axis of approximate symmetry being defined as straight line cutting the polygon in two halves in a way that their shapes are as similar as possible.)

Comment: This seems more of a mathematical question based on geometry and not GIS (I see no real G). I would try http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/geometry first